# Different kinds of shoots

Tags: identification, lily

Last year I planted one already flowering lily plant, in north eastern North Dakota. This year in its spot lots of shoots are coming up but there seems to be 4 different types of shoots coming up. Can someone please explain this to me?

[image: lilies]

[image: lilies2]

Follow up, not sure how it happen but the lilies grew into 3 different colors
[image: 3colors]

Comment: Can you add a picture?

Comment: I can't figure out how too

Comment: Hi @HeatherG. - you can [edit your post](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/24836/edit) and then click the little picture icon on the toolbar, which will bring up a drag and drop area that you can upload a picture from your computer. Alternatively, I often find it much easier to snap and upload a pic from my phone, you can download the StackExchange iPhone or Android app to do this :) For more help, [see this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/317795)

Comment: I used to use the official Imgur app for Android, but that stopped working for me, so I swapped to another 3rd party app called "Imgur Android".  Confusing but it works a lot better.

Comment: Got the pictures to work with the stackexchange app! Thanks @TimMalone for the help :)

Comment: Also, I'm not that good at identification but adding your location to your post might help those who are, in case it narrows anything down!

Comment: Will do! Thank you for the advice I really appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lilies are bulbs and can [propagate from just one plant](https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/chiwonlee/plsc368/student/papers02/mwebster/easterlily.html) by growing bulbils, bulblets or [offsets](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=101). Offsets grow near the parent in the ground and take a few years to flower.  Leaves are normally the same colour but shorter. Depending on species the juvenile leaves can have a slightly different shape.

I have seen the same thing you have observed in purchased bulbs in the second season or after major trauma like a chipmunk digging up the parent.  If the parent puts everything into flowering the next year the parent may not flower but it will have a lot of offsets.

No action is necessary, sit back and wait and you will have more lilies.